Understanding infimum and jordan measure cover by open and closed set
I'm self-studying the Jordan measure and its definitions. I have a question regarding how the outer measure $ m_o(E) $ behaves when $ E $ is a closed interval and we restrict the elementary set to be open.
I want to introduce a "Jordan-open measure" $ m_J(E) $ for a bounded set $ E $, defined as follows:

$ m_o(E) = \inf \{ m(B) : B \supset E, \, B \text{ is an open elementary set} \} $
$ m_i(E) = \sup \{ m(B) : B \subset E, \, B \text{ is an open elementary set} \} $

The Jordan-open measure exists if and only if $ m_o(E) = m_i(E) $.
Here's my specific scenario:

$ E = [0, 1] $ is a closed interval on the real line.
We see that $ m_o(E) = 1 $.

However, there's a peculiar aspect:

At the limit, when $ B $ approaches $ (0, 1) $ to cover $ E $, $ B $ technically doesn't cover $ [0, 1] $ entirely, since it excludes the endpoints 0 and 1. (For example, a sequence $ B_n = (0 - \frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n}) $ approaches $ (0, 1) $).
definition only uses inf { m(B) }, it doesn't concern how B behaves, but it nevertheless feels strange.

I understand that the standard Jordan measure uses both open and closed sets, avoiding this issue. I'm exploring this as a thought experiment.
Now, if I define a "Jordan-close measure," we get:

$ m_o(E) = \inf \{ m(B) : B \supset E, \, B \text{ is a closed elementary set} \} $
$ m_i(E) = \sup \{ m(B) : B \subset E, \, B \text{ is a closed elementary set} \} $

This problem doesn't occur either.
Questions:

Can one claim the Jordan-close measure is the same as the standard Jordan measure?
Can one claim the Jordan-open measure is the same as the standard Jordan measure? (despite the peculiar point I'm struggling with)


What do you mean by an "elementary set"? Concerning your $B_n = (-\frac 1n, 1 + \frac 1n)$, you claim it approaches $(0,1)$ and "technically doesn't cover $[0,1]$". A most curious statement. Did you not notice that $[0,1] \subset B_n$ for every $n$? How is it "not covered"? The intersection of all the $B_n$ is exactly $[0,1]$, not $(0,1)$.

To say that a sequence $A_n$ of sets converges to a set $A$, it not only requires for every $x \in A$ that $x \in A_n$ for large enough $n$, but also that for every $y \notin A$, that $y \notin A_n$ for large enough $n$. $B_n \to [0,1]$, not $(0,1)$, because both $0$ and $1$ are in every $B_n$. Nothing ever excludes them.

@PaulSinclair Sorry for late response. Since in "jordan open measure" i defined the set B to be a set of open interval, .. The inf of B_n becomes (0, 1) even though =(−1,1+1) .

No. You cannot just say the magic word "open", and suddenly the mathematical genie stops $0$ and $1$ at the door, saying "sorry, even though you have all the invitations, you still can't go inside." The infimum of the $B_n$ consists of every point that is in all of the $B_n$, and that includes $0$ and $1$.
